# JAVA_HOME for Logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to setup ELK stack for my Web Services Log Monitoring.
So I have setup all the parts for ELK Stack.

I am facing one issue in Log-stash. When I am running Log-stash, I am facing error, **could not load Java binary**
Although the simple fix it set the JAVA_HOME in environment variable.
But I don't want to set an environment variable, but what I want to set JAVA_HOME just for Log-stash. I have tried adding in startup.options, but to enable I must run system-install. When I am running system-install, I am facing the same error again.

I have added
**export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jre8**

then system-install file runs, but still on starting log-stash, I am getting the same error. What should I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can config in startup.options (logstash5.4 version):
Ex:

```
JAVA_HOME=/.../jdk1.8.0_121
JAVACMD=/.../jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java
```

Then use root role to start: **system-install**.

(You can use `update-java-alternatives --list` to list installed java versions with paths)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this configuration to the file- /etc/sysconfig/logstash, this file is read during startup by logstash.

This is what you should add:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jre8
```